Childhood counting book about a boy who goes to miniature worlds based on the numbers 1 to 10
Children's counting book. Both counting forward and backward to 10. Late 80's/early 90's
It had a child (male) going on an adventure in the woods behind his home? his grandparent's home? I don't remember. But each page was him visiting a miniature "world" based on the numbers (ie: 5 had everything grouped in fives. 8 would have everything grouped in eights) and he would be given one item.
He then enters a field of flowers with one girl (this would be for #10). They sit and talk, and she gives him a Forget-Me-Not.
On his trek back home, he meets with people who need items that he so happens to have as they are the items he was given to him in the first half. By the time he gets home, he only has the Forget-Me-Not.
I've tried searching through Goodreads lists, asking Reddit, even ChatGPT, but I keep coming up with blanks or the wrong book.
ADDITION: I would have read this book in the early to mid 1990s

I’m voting to close this question because it does not seem to include any science fiction or fantasy elements.

would not traveling to other worlds count as fiction?

Are they actually different worlds or him contextualizing the world in terms of the numbers?

Also posted to https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/18c5um5/tomtchildrens_book_magical_adventure_in_counting/ (which is fine... just noting it for others doing searches)

Do you remember anything about how he travels to the other worlds? Is a wizard zapping him around? Portals? Inherent travel ability? Unexplained, just on another world each page?

No
Just that he enters the forest and each page is a different world/town/setting.
